# Flex Layout 100% Height is too much

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm playing with flexout. I wanted to create the typical layout of a header content area and footer

Now when I set the body, and the main divs to 100% height the footer is truncated. Is this a  content area, 
See this [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/37TfmaBBPjwDhmSg1HuZ?p=preview)

```html
<html style="height: 100%">

<body style="height: 100%">
  <div style="height:100%;display:flex;background-color: lightblue;flex-direction:column">
    <div style="width: 600">Header</div>
    <div style="width: 500;display: flex;height: 100%">
      <div style="width:300">Nav</div>
      <div>Content</div>
    </div>
    <div style="height:50px">footer</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[[image]

what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

The `body` have by default a `margin` of `8px`.

---

> Most browsers will display the  element with the following default values:

```
body {
    display: block;
    margin: 8px;
}

body:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Copied from [W3C - HTML body Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_body.asp).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a godd starting point for you:

It offers a completely responsive flex design with header and footer.

```css
body,html{
  margin:0;padding:0;
  height:100%;
}
.Flx{
  display:-webkit-flex;
  display:-ms-flex;
  display:flex;
}
.Wrap{
  margin:0 auto;
  height:100%;
  max-width:600px;
  -webkit-flex-direction:column;
  -ms-flex-direction:column;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.Header{
  -webkit-flex:0 50px;
  -ms-flex:1;flex:0 50px;
  background:#ccc;
}
.Content{
  -webkit-flex:1;
  -ms-flex:1;
  flex:1;
}
nav{
  -webkit-flex:0 1 300px;
  -ms-flex:0 1 300px;
  flex:0 1 300px;
  background:#eee;
}
.Footer{
  -webkit-flex:0 50px;
  -ms-flex:1;flex:0 50px;
  background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="Flx Wrap">
  <div class="Flx Header">Header</div>
  <div class="Flx Content">
    <nav class="Flx">Nav</nav>
    <div>Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Flx Footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx for that hint. its a very good start point for that scenario. But my issue was to understand the issue why it has this offset. so Ii mark the other post as answer (explanation with the margin)

Comment: Yes, all browsers use defaults if you do not speciy them. I recommend a css reset such as meyers: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ to make sure browsers do what you expect before you start.

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove the margin on your body tag.

To be sure you make it look in every browser the same you can do a so called [css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Browsers can have different default styles. This short css file will reset all default styles to be the same.

## Solution

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html style="height: 100%">

<body style="height: 100%">
  <div style="height:100%;display:flex;background-color: lightblue;flex-direction:column">
    <div style="width: 600">Header</div>
    <div style="width: 500;display: flex;height: 100%">
      <div style="width:300">Nav</div>
      <div>Content</div>
    </div>
    <div style="height:50px">footer</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```